# AKS unable to pull ACR image ImagePullBackOff

Tags: azure, azure-aks, acr

I use Azure Kubernetes Service in order to perform docker images deployment from Azure Container Registry.
After deployment I got:

```
Failed to pull image "<reg_name>.azurecr.io/service:latest": [rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "<reg_name>.azurecr.io/service:latest": failed to resolve reference "<reg_name>.azurecr.io/service:latest": <reg_name>.azurecr.io/service:latest: not found, rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "<reg_name>.azurecr.io/service:latest": failed to resolve reference "<reg_name>.azurecr.io/service:latest": failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized]
```

I created service principal and got principal name and password (based on: https://anupams.net/using-image-pull-secrets-with-azure-container-registry/), which I put next into kubernetes secret.
Next inside my deployment.yml I used property: imagePullSecrets with previously created secret. But it still won't work after deployment and kubectl get pods reports the same issues:

```
service-deployment-cbf49bcd9-vs2jz   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          27m
```

I tried to log in using "docker login" command with previously created service principal credentials - it works. But not in AKS...
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the AKS ACR integration that leverages RBAC instead of using service principals with Kubernetes secrets.

Also Microsoft is recommending it:

> While pull secrets are commonly used, they bring additional management
> overhead. If you're using Azure Kubernetes Service, we recommend other
> options such as using the cluster's managed identity or service
> principal to securely pull the image without an additional
> imagePullSecrets setting on each pod.

You can do so by using the Azure CLI for an existing cluster [details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration?tabs=azure-cli#configure-acr-integration-for-existing-aks-clusters) or create a new cluster [details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration?tabs=azure-cli#configure-acr-integration-for-existing-aks-clusters). You can also create the role assignment on your own if you are using Terraform or Bicep.

Terraform example:

```
 resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
    scope                            = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
    role_definition_name             = "AcrPull"
    principal_id                     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
  }
```

Comment: I read a lot of solutions for this issue. If you're using terraform this is by far the best way IMHO.